# POST a file read from file system as multipart to REST service in PHP

Tags: php, file, magento, file-io, multipartform-data

I am trying to read a file(image file) using PHP from file system as a multipart file and POST it to a REST service. I am not sure how to do this really as I reading it from a file system.

Well the complications or unanswered questions are -

- What is the encoding that I should do when I read the file from the file system that would make it same as a multipart?
- After this, how do I set the multipart to do a HTTP Post to the REST?

  Any help on this would be great, samples/pointers to samples would be even greater.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Is `curl` insufficient for you?

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't want to use CURL...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967007/how-can-i-post-a-file-to-a-rest-server-without-writing-the-file-to-disk-with-php